Svg in <img> scaling wrong in Safari
I'm currently making a simple website and I want to embed discord rich presence svg that I get from some api here. I'm embeding it to the page using the <img> tag. Now, I'm trying to implement media queries that will allow the website to scale properly on different devices. I wrote a simple CSS that works on Chrome, Firefox and Opera and scales down the img element (svg) correctly. It also works on my Android phone with Chrome. However, the img scales incorrectly on Safari (both on Mac and iPhone versions). The svg becomes cropped and it doesn't want to fit inside the correctly scaling <img> container.
Expected result:

Current result:

I tried adding different css webkit rules and fiddling with different sizes. The issue doesn't occur when the  width is set to a constant number like 400px but I want the size to be responsive.


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech+Mono&display=swap);
a,
h2 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right top,
    from(#11998e),
    to(#28a859)
  );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #11998e, #28a859);
  color: transparent;
}
.hero-text,
footer {
  text-align: center;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Share Tech Mono", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
}
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #191919;
  color: #bbb;
}

.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #313131;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}

.hero {
  height: 30rem;
  margin: 0 4rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.section-intro,
main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 5.61rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.157rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #28a859);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2.369rem;
}
main {
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 10vw;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  max-width: 30rem;
}
.section-intro {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
section > ul > li {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
section > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: justify;
}
.section-intro > img {
  width: 3.6rem;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

a {
  font-size: inherit;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #28a859);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0c746b, #1a6e3a);
}

.discord-presence {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 40vw;
  min-width: 20vw;
}

footer {
  padding: 1.6rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4.209rem;
  }
  section {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    max-width: 25rem;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .discord-presence {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 55vw;
    min-width: 40vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.953rem;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.369rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.052rem;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.953rem;
  }
}


.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
<main>
 <div>
 <!-- More content goes here.... -->
 </div>
  <img class="discord-presence noselect" src="https://lanyard.cnrad.dev/api/175652881456693249" alt="" />
</main>
<footer>xxxxx</footer>




When you look at the SVG code returned by the API call, it contains a <foreignObject> element. There is a known bug in WebKit which prevents the <foreignObject> element being scaled. The bug has been open for 15 years, so you may have to dive into the WebKit source code and fix it yourself.
